# SQL: Remove duplicate foreign key from the table to be displayed

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

```
Orders
OrderNo          ProductName
1                Product A
2                Product B
1                Product C
3                Product C
2                Product D
```

WHERE the information belongs to the two (2) tables:

```
Orders
OrderNo          ProductID
1                1
2                2
1                3
3                3
2                4
```

AND

```
Products
ProductID        ProductName
1                Product A
2                Product B
3                Product C
4                Product D
```

The order number values are foreign keys coming from another table ('OrderNumbers') which are auto-generated. I tried using GROUP BY keyword, however, this is not allowed since I used INNER JOIN statements;

> Column Products.ProductName is invalid because it is not contained in either an agreegate function or the GROUP BY clause

The output should display:

```
Output
OrdersNo         
1                
2
3
```

**Update:** Tried using the DISTINCT keyword, but still displays the record with duplicate OrderNo (FK)

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: select distinct OrderNo from table?

Comment: "however, this is not allowed since I used INNER JOIN statements" This is not generally true. You must be misinterpreting the error message. Please post it.

Comment: @usr i agree to your statement

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` will serve your purpose here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderNo FROM Orders
```